# how to use the tables generated by Python/R in Power BI?

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi, powerquery, m

I am trying to use Python/R in Power BI. But I do now know how to use the table generated by Python. I do not even know where it is. Here is an example:

```
id  name    score
1   zhao    65
2   qian    98
3   sun 100
4   li  45
5   zhou    98
```

Let's say this is my data called id. I use this button [image] to read the data into Power BI.

Then I use this button [image] to start the Power Query Editor, from where I can use Python/R by clicking [image] in Transform.

Then I have a very simple Python code in Run Python script:

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
import pandas as pd

myid=dataset
myid.loc[:,'id']=myid.loc[:,'id']*100
```

Everything goes correctly until now. But you might notice that I use 'dataset' to represent the data, instead of the real data name 'id'. So I am wondering if the database name is always 'dataset' by default in Power BI?

When I finish coding, I have this:

[image]

You can see there is no new table called 'myid' in the left part. Furthermore, when I use the button [image] to apply this change, there are some changes happened in Power BI Desktop:

[image]

You can see there is no any new table here either. So, what I should do if I want to use Python generated table to do something else, such as drawing, or using another Python analysis somewhere else?

Or, maybe this is not the correct way to use Pythong in Power BI? So, if I want to use Python to analyze data and model them in Power BI. And the result can be used in Power BI for visualization, etc afterwards, what I should do?

Comment: Can  you edit in the M code for your query that can be found in the Advanced Editor?

Comment: @ Alexis Olson  Could you please explain a little bit more? I totally do not what M code is and how to use it to edit my query. Thanks

Comment: The code found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqItV.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what the M code looks like for an R script.

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows({{1,"zhao",65},{2,"qian",98},{3,"sun",100},{4,"li",45},{5,"zhou",98}},{"id","name","score"}),
    #"Run R script" = R.Execute("# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script#(lf)#(lf)myid <- dataset#(lf)myid$id <- 100*myid$id",[dataset=Source]),
    myid = #"Run R script"{[Name="myid"]}[Value]
in
    myid
```

The code in the R script window is simply

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script

myid <- dataset
myid$id <- 100*myid$id
```

When you enter that script it should create a new step or two.

[image: R Script]

Simply click on the Table in the Value column to drill down to that table (if it didn't do that automatically).

[image: Drilldown]

Comment: That is great! Could you please answer two more questions: 1. When I finish coding in R script window. The M code automatically changes. So I do not need to coe sth in M code by meself, right? 2. If I want to use the new table (myid here) in Power BI destop, for example, visualization. How can I do it? Now when I click 'Close and Apply', I still cannot see the new table in Power BI Desktop. Soory to bother, I just start studying Power BI for 2 days.

Comment: 1. Not. You shouldn't need to use the Advanced Editor if you don't want to. 2. The table shown in the last applied step should be the same table that loads into Power BI. If you want to load both tables, then duplicate the query and only run the script on one copy.

Comment: This really helps a lot. Thanks